# Search and replace div content with another div content

Tags: html, regex, replace

I am trying to find a way to replace a DIV that has a few other divs inside with another div that also has a few other divs inside. Tried to do it with a few different programs: Atom, Sublime, Visual Studio Code, PhpStorm but it didn't work.

It could probably be done using regex since the first div starts with `<div class="short-form">` and ends with

```
...id="submitbtn_intakeFormShortAutofillSubmit"/>
    </form>
</div>
                    </div>
```

but my problem is probably the number of tabs, spaces and newlines.

Just to mention, I don't have to make this active on a webpage, but inside hundreds of html pages on my hard drive, so if you can recommend some free software that can do it, it's also good.

Comment: What regex did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
<div class="short-form">[\s\S]*?id="submitbtn_intakeFormShortAutofillSubmit"\/>\s*<\/form>\s*<\/div>\s*<\/div>
```

see it [live](https://regex101.com/r/2P1c3g/1)

Comment: You beat me too it, but I figured I'd answer anyway!  On that note, do you really need the `?` after the `[\s\S]*`?

Comment: It works great and thank you so much for it. It works with open files, but it doesn't find the text when I regex search multiple files in a folder (in Atom) do you have any idea why that is ?

Comment: I don't know atom well, I'll take a look at it @Vrle

Comment: Please don't spend more of your time on my problem. You helped me more then enough! If I can't solve this small part of it, I don't deserve to solve it at all :) @Thomas Ayoub

Answer (score 2):

Yep, this is very possible!  Here's how you do it:

```
<div class="short-form"[\s\S]*id="submitbtn_intakeFormShortAutofillSubmit"\/>\s*<\/form>\s*<\/div>\s*<\/div>
```

Break it down!

- `<div class="short-form"` match anything that starts with `<div class="short-form"`
- `[\s\S]*` matech 0 or more of anything that is white space or is *not* whitespase (So bassically match anything)
- `id="submitbtn_intakeFormShortAutofillSubmit"\/>` match anything that matches  `id="submitbtn_intakeFormShortAutofillSubmit"/>`
- `\s*` match 0 or more whitespace
- repeate the last two a few times!

[Here's an example on regexr!](http://regexr.com/3fkno)